# New e-commerce site: stuck with D6 Ubercart for now?

Tags: ubercart, commerce

Client needs a shopping cart in a hurry. The spec is fairly straightforward, but will need weight categories for shipping and payments through Worldpay.

I'd love to do this with D7 and excited about [Drupal Commerce](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/), but I don't think it's there yet. I spent today playing with D7 Ubercart, and while it felt quite stable I don't think many contrib modules have been upgraded and I'm going to struggle.

So my instinct says build the thing in D6 Ubercart for now, then look to upgrade to Drupal Commerce further down the line. Sound like a plan?